# How to Convert NSManagedObject with relationships to Swift class?

Tags: swift, core-data

I’ve been working on an App for tracking personal finances.  So far I’ve been using Swift classes as an abstraction layer since I didn’t know what I wanted to use as the persistent store.  I have objects such as Budget, BudgetGroup, BudgetItem, Transaction, and Allocation.

BudgetGroup, BudgetItem, Transaction, and Allocation are all unique to a particular instance of a Budget. There will be a new Budget, and thus, new BudgetGroups, BudgetItems, Transactions, and Allocations each month.

I am now trying to implement a persistent store using Core Data.  My defined entities look like:

[image: Linked Core Data model]

Converting the properties is straight forward

```
    func fromManagedObject() -> Transaction {

        let transaction = Transaction(

            identifier: identifier!,
            budget: nil,
            transactionType: TransactionType( rawValue: transactionType ?? "" ) ?? TransactionType.expense,
            date: date!,
            amount: Currency( significand: amount ),
            summary: summary!,
            memo: memo,
            allocations: []

        )

        return transaction

    }
```

Because of the circular nature of the graph, the problem is converting the "to-many" relationships from the managed object.  Using something simple like:

```
let mappedAllocations = (allocations?.allObjects as! [AllocationMO]).map { $0.fromManagedObject( ) }
```

can end up in a recursive loop and ultimately crash.

Is my Core Data model too complex?  I.e. should it NOT have circular paths?

Am I defeating the best features of Core Data and wasting resources by converting NSManagedObjects to my abstraction layer?

Would it be better to implement a set of protocols that the Core Data entities conform to, thus avoiding having to convert from one model to another?

Answer (score 0):

Your first question, regarding *too complex*…  Yes, your data model is too complex.  Regarding *circular paths*, not all circular paths are bad.  *Inverse relationships* form small circular paths that are good.  But when a Budget owns Transactions and a Transaction owns Allocations but a Budget also owns Allocations directly, although it is possible to do stuff like this and may in some cases be done for performance optimization, it is difficult, problematic and something that you would not want to do in early design phases, unless you are *really smart*.  This recommendation is true for any object-oriented or database design – with or without Core Data.

Your second question, regarding the *abstraction layer*.  If your abstraction layer is an interface to a front end (iOS or macOS  user interface), then you are defeating one of the advantages of Core Data by using an abstraction layer.  For every rule there is an exception, but NSManagedObject instances can and usually should be plugged directly into your user interface.  On the back end, of course there will be an abstraction layer of JSON or whatever objects.

Your third question, regarding *protocols*, disappears if you don't use the abstraction layer.